# Name an inferred type in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml, naming, abbreviation

Assume, you have a declaration with an inferred type:

```
let f x y = x +. y
```

Now if you use this type in some other inferred type:

```
let g h x = (if x > 0. then h else f) x x
```

You obviously have a type-identity between `h` and `f`. If, however, the type of `f` becomes complicated and you still want it to be inferred (say you do some code-generation), the type of `g` easily becomes unreadable.

Is there a way to introduce a type declaration in the form of:

```
type mytype = <type of the function f above>
```

And have the typechecker stick to it, i.e. in the above example, it should yield:

```
val g : mytype -> float -> float
```

Comment: No. There's no way to define a type synonym as the type of an expression. You need to explicitly specify the type. Why is this a problem for you? What are you actually trying to do? I suspect that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The problem is that I am indeed generating code that has a rather complex type. I rely on the Ocaml type checker (and an equivalence property of the original and the generated code) to prove type-safety of the original code. Due to the complexity of the inferred types, the error messages are hardly readable (and I suspect some performance impact as well). Defining the type myself would mean to implement type inference for the original code, which I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort-of do this by indirecting through an class. The class name stands in for the type synonym that you can't write yourself.

```
let f x y = x +. y

class t = object
  method f = f
end

let f_short = new t

let g h x = (if x > 0. then h else f_short)#f x x
```

Unhappily, this will have some runtime cost. If you are desperate you could duplicate all the definitions, calling the non-class ones and using the others for type errors - that would be pretty obscure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, a function in OCaml is just a regular value, that has a type. For example, a type for function `f` is `float -> float -> float`. You can create a type abbreviation for this type:

```
type binop = float -> float -> float
```

You can later refer to this type, to make your type annotations more succinct:

```
let g : binop -> float -> float = fun h x -> (if x > 0. then h else f) x x;
```

But note, that type system in OCaml is structural, not nominal. In layman terms, that means, that types are checked not by name, but by contents, unless you hide the contents by module abstraction. So, this `binop` is just an abbreviation, the type is still `float -> float -> float`

Comment: I am pretty familiar with OCaml's type system. My question was if I could introduce an abbreviation without  having to manually define its right hand side.

Comment: You mean, that you are looking for some kind of `#typeof` operator?

Comment: Basically yes, but not as part some reflection API, but merely as a type-expression.